# HTML form select option triggers text field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, triggers

I'm trying to get a text field to appear when the user selects a certain option in a form select. I found exactly what I need at http://jsfiddle.net/0ak3b3z1/

However, when I copy this exact code into an html document, it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.
Here is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#industry').on('change',function(){
  var selection = $(this).val(); 
  console.log("Detected change..." + selection);
  $("#SaaSMeetings").toggle($(this).val()=="SaaS");
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<label for="">Industry?</label>
    <select id="industry">
        <option value="Telesales">Telesales</option>
        <option value="Media">Media/Advertising</option>
        <option value="SaaS">SaaS</option>
        <option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
        <option value="Automobile">Automobile</option>
    </select>

<!-- Show Metric Input based on Industry Selection -->

<input type="text" id="telesalesCalls" placeholder="How many calls?" style="display:none">
<input type="text" id="SaaSMeetings"  placeholder="How many meetings?" style="display:none">
<input type="text" id="MediaMeetings" placeholder="How many meetings?" style="display:none">
<input type="text" id="InsuranceCalls" placeholder="How many calls?" style="display:none">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to include jQuery. Plus you must place the javascript at end (after DOM elements are defined).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="">Industry?</label>
    <select id="industry">
    <option value="Telesales">Telesales</option>
    <option value="Media">Media/Advertising</option>
    <option value="SaaS">SaaS</option>
    <option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
    <option value="Automobile">Automobile</option>
</select>

<!-- Show Metric Input based on Industry Selection -->
<input type="text" id="telesalesCalls" placeholder="How many calls?" style="display:none">
<input type="text" id="SaaSMeetings" placeholder="How many meetings?" style="display:none">
<input type="text" id="MediaMeetings" placeholder="How many meetings?" style="display:none">
<input type="text" id="InsuranceCalls" placeholder="How many calls?" style="display:none">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#industry').on('change', function () {
        var selection = $(this).val();
        console.log("Detected change..." + selection);
        $("#SaaSMeetings").toggle($(this).val() == "SaaS");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign is used with the jquery library, and you're not including this library.

So just add jquery library before the js code.

Just Include this code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include this line in your code.

`<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'>      </script>`